# Can't sign into Xcode: "Couldn’t communicate with a helper application."

Tags: xcode

Today, my apple developer account login session expired, but when I try to sign in again I get the following popup/error:

```
Couldn’t communicate with a helper application.

Try your operation again. If that fails, quit and relaunch the application and try again.
```

[image]

I've tried restarting my computer, quiting and reopining xcode, and now I'm not sure what to do since the account needs to be logged in in order to run the ios app on my device. Does anyone know how to help with this? If you need more information on this then just let me know and I'll add it to my question :) Thanks!

**Edit:**

My current Xcode version is 13.0

Comment: try to update xcode

Comment: as said above, try to update the Xcode. close and quit the Xcode completely. restart your machine and try again.

Comment: Ok, I've uninstalled and reinstalled xcode and it worked this time! Thanks :) You can post your comment as answer if you like and then I can accept it